# Uso do typedef para ponteiro

Tags: c, ponteiro, declaração-de-variável, typedef

Se eu já defini um ponteiro para minha estrutura por que eu não consigo fazer a alocação dela.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct ponto
{
   int a, b;
};

typedef struct ponto *Ponteiro; // define um ponteiro para estrutura ponto 
typedef struct ponto estrutura; // aqui chamo a estrutura ponto de estrutura

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    Ponteiro  = malloc(sizeof(estrutura)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assim?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ponto {
   int a, b;
};

typedef struct ponto * Ponteiro;
typedef struct ponto estrutura;

int main() { 
    Ponteiro p = malloc(sizeof(estrutura));
    printf("%p", (void *)p);
}
```

Faltava colocar uma variável, você não pode declarar uma variável sem dar nome para ela.

Ficaria até melhor assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct ponto {
   int a, b;
} Estrutura;

typedef Estrutura* Ponteiro;

int main() { 
    Ponteiro p = malloc(sizeof(Estrutura));
    printf("%p", (void *)p);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hF94Uq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rehbqpnp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/TypedefPointer.c).